# linq-to-sql group by with count and custom object model

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm looking to fill an object model with the count of a linq-to-sql query that groups by its key.

The object model looks somewhat like this:

```
public class MyCountModel()
{
  int CountSomeByte1 { get; set; }
  int CountSomeByte2 { get; set; }
  int CountSomeByte3 { get; set; }
  int CountSomeByte4 { get; set; }
  int CountSomeByte5 { get; set; }
  int CountSomeByte6 { get; set; }
}
```

This is what I have for the query:

```
var TheQuery = from x in MyDC.TheTable
               where ListOfRecordIDs.Contains(x.RecordID) && x.SomeByte < 7
               group x by x.SomeByte into TheCount
               select new MyCountModel()
               {
                   CountSomeByte1 = TheCount.Where(TheCount => TheCount.Key == 1)
                                            .Select(TheCount).Count(),

                   CountSomeByte2 = TheCount.Where(TheCount => TheCount.Key == 2)
                                            .Select(TheCount).Count(),     
                   .....

                   CountSomeByte6 = TheCount.Where(TheCount => TheCount.Key == 6)
                                            .Select(TheCount).Count(), 

               }.Single();
```

`ListOfRecordIDs` is list of longs that's passed in as a parameter. All the CountSomeByteN are underlined red. How do you do a count of grouped elements with the group's key mapped to an object model?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `select` is taking each element of your group and projecting them to identical newly created `MyCountModel`s, and you're only using one of them. Here's how I'd do it:

```
var dict = MyDC.TheTable
    .Where(x => ListOfRecordIDs.Contains(x.RecordID) && x.SomeByte < 7)
    .GroupBy(x => x.SomeByte)
    .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.Count());

var result = new MyCountModel()
{
    CountSomeByte1 = dict[1];
    CountSomeByte2 = dict[2];
    CountSomeByte3 = dict[3];
    CountSomeByte4 = dict[4];
    CountSomeByte5 = dict[5];
    CountSomeByte6 = dict[6];
}
```

EDIT: Here's one way to do it in one statement. It uses an extension method called `Into`, which basically works as `x.Into(f)` == `f(x)`. In this context, it can be viewed as like a `Select` that works on the whole enumerable rather than on its members. I find it handy for eliminating temporary variables in this sort of situation, and if I were to write this in one statement, it's probably how I'd do it:

```
public static U Into<T, U>(this T self, Func<T, U> func)
{
    return func(self);
}

var result = MyDC.TheTable
    .Where(x => ListOfRecordIDs.Contains(x.RecordID) && x.SomeByte < 7)
    .GroupBy(x => x.SomeByte)
    .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.Count())
    .Into(dict => new MyCountModel()
    {
        CountSomeByte1 = dict[1];
        CountSomeByte2 = dict[2];
        CountSomeByte3 = dict[3];
        CountSomeByte4 = dict[4];
        CountSomeByte5 = dict[5];
        CountSomeByte6 = dict[6];
    });
```

Comment: Do i also need an orderby to make sure that CountSomeByte1 = dict[1]; Also, is there a way to make it work in just one statement?

Comment: 1) No. `dict` is a `Dictionary`, and `1` is a dictionary key, not an array index. `dict[1]` will be the count of the records whose `SomeByte` is 1, because that's how the grouping was done.

2) I'm sure there's a way, but I doubt that it would be as straightforward. I'll play around with it.

Comment: What if you use .Select and then project the dictionary onto the object model's properties? Would that work? .Select(x => new MyCountModel() { ... }); ?

Comment: `Select` is for turning one sort of sequence into some other sort of sequence. In this case, the `Dictionary` is interpreted as an `IEnumerable` of `KeyValuePair`s, but you don't want to get a sequence out of it, but rather a single object. Thus, `Select` really isn't the right tool. Now, you might think of your `MyCountModel` as being kind of like a sequence, but the language doesn't let you treat it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Your range variable is not correct in the subqueries:

```
     CountSomeByte6 = TheCount.Where(TheCount => TheCount.Key == 6)
                                        .Select(TheCount).Count(),
```

In method notation you don't need the extra select:

```
CountSomeByte6 = TheCount.Where(theCount => theCount.Key == 6).Count(),
```

If you want to use it anyway:

```
CountSomeByte6 = TheCount.Where(theCount => theCount.Key == 6).Select(theCount => theCount).Count(),
```

Comment: ok, the syntax errors do go away but now, at runtime, I get a "Sequence contains more than one element" error.

Comment: You are calling Single, which means you expect exactly one element, but apparently the query returns more than one element, just as the message says.

Comment: Yes, I'm calling Single because I'm only looking for one MyCountModel() to be returned. Why is it returning more than 1??

Comment: read the documentation of `Single`. You need First or FirstOrDefault.

Comment: In fact, it doesn't work: even though it doesn't crash, the results aren't accurate.

Comment: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx