# linq select from dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [linq-to-sql group by with count and custom object model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12644136/linq-to-sql-group-by-with-count-and-custom-object-model)

I have a linq-to-sql query that groups and counts and the result ends up in a dictionary. I want to map the dictionary to an object model's property. The object model looks like this:

```
public class MyCountModel()
{
  int CountSomeByte1 { get; set; }
  int CountSomeByte2 { get; set; }
  int CountSomeByte3 { get; set; }
  int CountSomeByte4 { get; set; }
  int CountSomeByte5 { get; set; }
  int CountSomeByte6 { get; set; }
}
```

I want to map the dictionary so that the query ends like this:

```
var TheQuery = MyDC.SomeTable
               .Where(...)
               .GroupBy(...)
               .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x=> x.Count()
               .Select(m => new MyCountModel()
               {
                  CountSomeByte1 = ..., // the value where Key is 1
                  CountSomeByte2 = ...., // the value where Key is 2
                  ....
                  CountSomeByte6 = .... // the value where Key is 6
                });
```

How could I write something like this?
Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: are you using DBML? that's a pretty simple way to do this

Comment: @ThomSmith: no, it's the continuation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to select anything. I think you simply want to 'reduce' the query to a single value:

```
var dictionary = MyDC.SomeTable
               .Where(...)
               .GroupBy(...)
               .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x=> x.Count());

var result = new  MyCountModel
               {
                  CountSomeByte1 = dictionary[1],
                  CountSomeByte2 = dictionary[2],
                  ....
                  CountSomeByte6 = dictionary[6]
                });
```